# Manipulate theme version - hook into wp_get_theme()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I want to alter the version of a theme, returned by `wp_get_theme()`. I checked in the source code, and saw that `wp_get_theme()` returns `new WP_Theme( $stylesheet, $theme_root );` and there is no hook involved in the process...

I then went one step deeper and checked in `class WP_Theme` to maybe find a hook, but from what I've seen there is no useful hook in there either.

So can you give me any insight on how to manipulate the theme version returned by `wp_get_theme()` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible to change the theme version, without actually updating the themes style.css file.

You have a few options now:

1. Use something elese than the theme version
2. update the themes style.css file
3. add to the theme version, for example a date (but that won't be refleced when someone gets the theme version somewhere else

What is your goal? For keeping the most recent files from a build proccess out of the cache, I personally recommend using a HASH in the filename, over the theme version. This is how it is done in sage10 and bud.js.

Comment: Before I overrode a JS file in the child theme to make some changes, I tested the changes I had to make directly in the parent theme file. Usually, when I do this, I change the version of the theme (that is appended at the end of the JS file) with `time()` so that I overcome caching... This time I forgot that, and now an `alert('dsads');` is cached when the page loads and a specific event happens... Of course the alert is not there anymore, only the cache remained for the current version of my theme... This is what I'm trying to fix...

Comment: I altered style.css, adding a `.1` at the end of the current version. And indeed, the constant used by enqueue_script was altered!!! So, I ended up editing a source file, but the file will anyway be replaced when the theme updates in a natural way, so no harm done! You helped me a lot with your second suggestion above. Thanks a lot!